# How to know how many input features and output features an image should have?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch, generative-adversarial-network

I'm trying to learn GAN's and I need to give input and output features for the image.I'm working on mnist dataset and how can I know the number of input and output features an image should have?

Answer (score 0):

The input and output features should match the shape of the images in the actual dataset.

In the MNIST dataset, you can get the shape using:

```
from keras.datasets import mnist

(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) =  mnist.load_data()

print(x_train.shape)
```

and you'll see that it's (28, 28). But you need the color channel to be in their for your model so you can add the 1 color channel the images are in like so (This depends on where you're getting the dataset from):

```
x_train = x_train.reshape(x_train.shape + (1,))
x_test = x_test.reshape(x_test.shape + (1, ))
```